# Georeference in ArcGIS to a known scale?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, georeferencing

If I'm georefencing an engineer's drawing and the scale is 1:250 is there anyway I can input this into ArcGIS for accuracy once I've selected a few points to georeference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing that scale really only helps you prior to georeferencing. With it, you could do some math with the image resolution and size to determine the real-world size of the image when you brought it in. It wouldn't do a lot for accuracy because there may be distortions introduced in the scan of the drawing. But if you're georeferencing, the points you set are going to override any sort of scale and introduce their own distortions as the image is warped to fit your control points.  At best, knowing that scale gives you an idea of how accurately the image represents the data portrayed and what you can expect as from data digitized from it (just like a map scale).